# How can I sort file names into a folder based on their name

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to move files into folders based on the start of their names,

For example, I have six files, xx_0_1.png, xx_0_2.png, xx_1_1.png, xxx_0_1.png, xxx_0_2.png, xxx_1_1.png

(they do not always follow this pattern of having three)

I need them to sort into folders based on what the characters before the _0 (because there can be something like hello_world_0_1.png, names never include integers. the numbers after don't have a limit on how large they are.

so if I had fruit_0_1.png, fruit_0_2.png, fruit_1_1.png, fence_0_1.png, fence_0_2.png, hello_world_0_1.png and hello_world_0_2.png they would sort into folders like this:

fruit

- fruit_0_1.png
- fruit_0_2.png
- fruit_1_1.png

fence

- fence_0_1.png
- fence_0_2.png

hello_world

- hello_world_0_1.png
- hello_world_0_2.png

the format for the names of the png files are always (sometext)*(firstnumber)*(secondnumber).png
the sometext can include underscores and often does however it never includes a number. firstnumber and secondnumber can be as large as they end up being (usually always less than 20 but can be more)
and the files are always of type .png

I have tried some solutions from other stack overflow questions however I have not been able to find a solution yet.

the closest I have gotten is having each file individually get sorted into their own folder (which is not what I want), This example is what I have:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
cd ..
del %%~na
pause
```

It currently puts each file into their own folder instead of splitting after the name.

Comment: Okay, I have tried some examples from other stack overflow posts but none have worked, the closest I have gotten is having each file individually get sorted into their own folder (which is not what I want), This example is what I have:
`@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
cd ..
del %%~na
pause
`
It currently puts each file into their own folder instead of splitting after the name.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and put your code there! Besides the fact that code is hard to read in comments, they might be cleaned up somewhen in future, leaving an incomplete thread behind, so please make sure every relevant information becomes added to the post itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example script:

```bat
@For %%F In ("*_*_*.png")Do @(Set "oF=%%F"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%D In ("!oF:_=\!\..\..")Do @(Set "oD=%%~dpnD"
        Set "oD=!oD:%__CD__%=!"
        RoboCopy . "!oD:\=_!" "%%F" /Mov>NUL)
    EndLocal)
```

*As your question is a code request only, I am not going to provide an explanation of how it works, how to use it, or expand upon it for any scenario outside of your question at the time of its posting.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%V in ('2^> nul set "$ITEM["') do set "%%V="
cd /D "C:\Projects" & rem // (specify target rooot directory here)
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*_*_*.png" ^| findstr /I /R "[^_]_[0-9][0-9]*_[0-9][0-9]*\.png$"
') do (
    call :SUB "%%~nF"
    set /A "IDX-=2" & set "NAME=_" & for /L %%I in (0,1,!IDX!) do set "NAME=!NAME!!$ITEM[%%I]!_"
    ECHO mkdir "%%~dpF!NAME:~1,-1!" 2> nul
    ECHO move "%%~fF" "%%~dpF!NAME:~1,-1!\%%~nxF"
)

endlocal
exit /B

:SUB
    set /A "IDX=0" & set "FILE=%~1"
    set "$ITEM[!IDX!]=%FILE:_=" & set /A "IDX+=1" & set "$ITEM[!IDX!]=%"
    exit /B
```

After having tested for the correct output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` commands**!